# How to python pip install for Python 2.7, having using Python 3.6 before on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

- I would like to ask about how to use `pip install` for Python 2.7, when I previously installing for and using Python 3.6 ? (*I now have to versions of Python on Windows)

  `pip install ...` keeps installing for Python 3.6

I need to use the previous version, to rewrite the code in Python 2.7. (this is for building a Kivy app, **although Kivy says it now supports Python 3 but it also says * *Warning.***) In order to do this, I have to `import` necessary modules : `kivy` and `numpy`.

Hope for feedbacks on this, Thanks.

Comment: windows or linux? just run `pip` from absolute path. In windows it's in `scripts` subdir of python install

Comment: specify python version : pip2.7 install

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre. `cd` to the `Scripts` folder solves this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  Sorry, but how is it to `pip` in Linux terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the 2 versions really installed, you should have a `pip2` or `pip2.x` available in your `PATH`

Comment: Thanks. I was able to run `pip3` but not `pip2`, nor `pip2.x`. **But now changing `cd` to the `Scripts` folder solves it.