# How to use pip on a specific version of python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

So my problem is that I have two versions of python: 2.7 and 3.2. I want to install pycrypto on the 2.7 one but when I try to do this:

`python2.7 pip install pcrypto`

Or:

`pip2.7 install pycrypto`

It says that `python2.7` or `pip2.7` is not a recognized command.

What should I do?

Comment: windows/linux ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to python pip install for Python 2.7, having using Python 3.6 before on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630267/how-to-python-pip-install-for-python-2-7-having-using-python-3-6-before-on-wind)

Answer (score 0):

`pip` installs a library for any version of Python 2

`pip3` installs a library for any version of Python 3

Answer (score 0):

On linux terminal, type:

```
whereis pip
```

It will print all available paths to `pip` installations. Copy-paste the full path to the desired `pip`, e.g.:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install pcrypto
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `pip` of a specific python interpreter you can use this interpreter with the `-m` option to use the specific pip.

```
python -m pip ...
```

`...` should be replaced with the desired pip commands.

The `-m` option allows to run a library module as a script (in this case the associated pip)